# Find pods with old container that needs to be restarted

Tags: json, kubernetes, jq

I have the following minimal example of a pod list:

```
{
    "items": [
        {
            "metadata": {
                "name": "app"
            },
            "spec": {
                "containers": [
                    {
                        "image": "some-registry/istio/proxyv2:new-version",
                        "name": "istio-proxy"
                    },
                    {
                        "image": "some-registry/app/app:latest",
                        "name": "app"
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "metadata": {
                "name": "another-app"
            },
            "spec": {
                "containers": [
                    {
                        "image": "some-registry/istio/proxyv2:old-version",
                        "name": "istio-proxy"
                    },
                    {
                        "image": "some-registry/another-app/another-app:latest",
                        "name": "another-app"
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "metadata": {
                "name": "no-sidecar-app"
            },
            "spec": {
                "containers": [
                    {
                        "image": "some-registry/no-sidecar-app/no-sidecar-app:latest",
                        "name": "no-sidecar-app"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Now I want a list of pod names that have a sidecar of `proxyv2:old-version`. So I tried filtering for the all pods that have such a sidecar and then try to filter out the ones that already have the new version. But I just can't find the right query.

Using `.items[] | select(.spec.containers[].image | test("some-registry/istio/proxyv2:.*"))` gives me a list that contains the pods having a sidecar but if I then try to filter the pods with the old sidecar like this `.items[] | select(.spec.containers[].image | test("some-registry/istio/proxyv2:.*")) | select(.spec.containers[].image | test(".*:old-version$") | not)` I suddenly get the first pod output twice instead of only the one pod that still runs the old sidecar.

Can someone add the right filter/statement I'm missing?

https://jqplay.org/s/4COz0LNtLiF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are testing all images against the old version. As soon as a single image does not contain the old version string, you have a match. Your "app" images do not contain the old version, therefore your full item is matched.

You want to use `all(… | not)` or `any(…) | not` instead:

```
.items[]
| select(.spec.containers[].image | test("^some-registry/istio/proxyv2:"))
| select(all(.spec.containers[].image; test(":old-version$") | not))
```

```
.items[]
| select(.spec.containers[].image | test("^some-registry/istio/proxyv2:"))
| select(any(.spec.containers[].image; test(":old-version$")) | not)
```

But maybe the better solution is checking your condition with `any` and `all`:

```
.items[]
| select(
    .spec.containers
    | map(.image)
    | any(test("^some-registry/istio/proxyv2:")) and all(test(":old-version$")|not)
)
```

To me that feels a like a more natural description of the problem.

Comment: I'm still trying to wrap my head around the right kind of thinking on these tasks, especially where to slice the data and to apply the right filter. So thanks for the solution. It really improved my understanding of jq!